# .htaccess file is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|gallary|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Above is the code exist in .htaccess.

I want the rules such as every request made to main domain or subdomain must hit the index,php file in the domain root.

exm.
api.xyz.com, api.xyz.com/register, api.xyz.com/login
all this request must have to go to index.php

I am facing this error on ipage web host.
Please suggest if anything wrong the host too.

Comment: You need to make sure that rewrite rules in .htaccess is allowed in your apache server.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. The rewrite rules are active. One cakephp application is running on same host. So its bit clear that rewrite rules are working.

Comment: Did you mean to have `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?=$1 [L]` instead? Just making sure...

Comment: @Grumpy index.php/extraquerystring is perfectly allowed in php and that's what most of us usually do so you won't worry about ? and & characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is not working on.
I am using this .htaccess for the subdomain. "No input file specified." Error I am getting.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you use to test it?